# Android: ViewPager2 is resetting my activity view

Tags: android, android-activity, view, android-viewpager, reset

I have implemented ViewPager2 in an activity. It has 3 fragments only.
I am running some Service (binded) for some background work that then updates the UI in Activity and one of the fragments.

The problem is that, on one device (Android 13), it randomly resets the whole Activity View (not just the fragment) and aparently onCreate is also not called. It does not crash, but it just resets all views of that Activity.

Here is my code:

Activity layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MyActivity">
.....


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm){
private val mFragmentList: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mFragmentList.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return mFragmentList[position]
}

fun addFragment(frag: Fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add(frag)
   }
}
```

Pager Setup:

```
       myPager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
      val adapter = MyPagerAdapter(this)
      adapter.addFragment(mcf)
        adapter.addFragment(fdf)
        myPager.adapter = adapter
```

When I used `offscreenPageLimit = 2` to retain the views. It does not reset the fragment, but it still resets the Activity view.

I had same code previously, which didnt have ViewPager2 and that used to work fine.

Any idea what could be wrong? Are there bugs in ViewPager2? Should i use ViewPager instead?

And what callback am I supposted to get if Activity view resets.